# Algorithm for Minimum spanning tree

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms, trees

I was wondering if the following one is an algorithm that finds a MST for an edge-weighted graph G.

START: G'=G

RECURSION: If G' is acyclic, the algorithm returns G'. If there's a cycle C in G' and e is the maximum weighted edge in C: remove e from G'.

I can't find a counterexample but I'm not sure how to prove this.

Comment: If there is more than one cycle, which one does the algorithm choose first? Or does that not matter?

Comment: @JaapScherphuis It doesn't matter

Comment: If you tackle the cycles in order of their weightiest edge, then it is the [Reverse-delete algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse-delete_algorithm). It is ok to do the cycles in any other order because the set of {edges that are the worst in some cycle} does not change. Deleting the worst edge $e$ in cycle $C$ will not affect which edge is worst in any other. In any cycle that contains $e$ and a worse edge, you could replace $e$ by $C-e$ and simplify which results in another cycle that still contains the same worst edge, so that worst edge will still be tackled eventually.

Comment: @JaapScherphuis Thank you very much!!